# nodes near coords with pgfplots polar

Tags: pgfplots, polar

Using pgfplots for polar charts, is it possible to write the y value at the edge of every data line, in a way that the line will not hide the value (as shown in the picture)?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        ymin=0, ymax=25, ytick=\empty,
        nodes near coords,
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick}
    ]
    \addplot+ [polar comb]
    coordinates {
        (0,21.6)(30,5.3)(60,5.5)(90,11.4)
        (120,4.0)(150,6.6)(180,15.8)(210,5.2)
        (240,5.5)(270,10.6)(300,3.4)(330,5.2)
    };
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Yes, you can make the anchor of the nodes depend on the angle, i.e. the `x` coordinate. One option is

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        ymin=0, ymax=30, ytick=\empty,
        nodes near coords,
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        visualization depends on={x\as\myx},
        nodes near coords style={anchor=\myx-180}
    ]
    \addplot+ [polar comb]
    coordinates {
        (0,21.6)(30,5.3)(60,5.5)(90,11.4)
        (120,4.0)(150,6.6)(180,15.8)(210,5.2)
        (240,5.5)(270,10.6)(300,3.4)(330,5.2)
    };
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also add a dependence on the `\coordindex`.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        ymin=0, ymax=25, ytick=\empty,
        nodes near coords,
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        visualization depends on={x+(\coordindex==0?90:0)\as\myx},
        nodes near coords style={anchor=\myx-180}
    ]
    \addplot+ [polar comb]
    coordinates {
        (0,21.6)(30,5.3)(60,5.5)(90,11.4)
        (120,4.0)(150,6.6)(180,15.8)(210,5.2)
        (240,5.5)(270,10.6)(300,3.4)(330,5.2)
    };
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or make it `x` and `y` dependent.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        ymin=0, ymax=25, ytick=\empty,
        nodes near coords,
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        visualization depends on={(y>15?-90:x-180)\as\myanchor},
        nodes near coords style={anchor=\myanchor}
    ]
    \addplot+ [polar comb]
    coordinates {
        (0,21.6)(30,5.3)(60,5.5)(90,11.4)
        (120,4.0)(150,6.6)(180,15.8)(210,5.2)
        (240,5.5)(270,10.6)(300,3.4)(330,5.2)
    };
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Comment: @user-ik You're welcome!